# Someone hacked into my Minecraft account and changed its name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Somebody hacked into my account and changed my name. My account name was damianea103. But it's DonkeyPrecum. I can't change it unless I wait 30 days. And I don't wanna go online with that username. How do I change it (or at least contact Mojang to change it for me)?

Comment: If you [contact support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new)  they *might* change it before then. That's probably your best bet.

Comment: I'd also change your password

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  I went from TimmyJim to Revenger and some numbers.  Really you should just wait it out.  Other than that, try what Unionhawk stated, though they probably won't/can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your web browser to save passwords (or any web browser not on your own computer you used to log into Minecraft's / Mojang's website), you may have had someone else do it easily that way. Also, I would always recommend you **never** log into **any** account you are wanting to keep on **any** computer that isn't yours... ... and **never** ***ever*** trust a not-well-known Minecraft launcher (and totally ***not*** a hack client -- those have been known to steal logins and/or infect the system you run it on).

EDIT: Like someone responded to you by comment there, if you have the proof still that you purchased the account, use that when requested by Mojang support.